# Mingw and cmake compile OpenCV (including OpenCV-Contrib) error

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation

when I using mingw compile opencv(with opencv-contrib), the process always stop at “Linking CXX shared library ....\bin\libopencv_world470.dll”.

like this:

```
Linking CXX shared library ..\..\bin\libopencv_world470.dll
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
...
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
D:/My_Working_Apps/Anaconda3/Library/lib/libhdf5.lib(CMakeFiles/hdf5-static.dir/H5Ztrans.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x3026): undefined reference to `__isa_available'
D:/My_Working_Apps/Anaconda3/Library/lib/libhdf5.lib(CMakeFiles/hdf5-static.dir/H5Ztrans.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x3355): undefined reference to `__isa_available'
D:/My_Working_Apps/Anaconda3/Library/lib/libhdf5.lib(CMakeFiles/hdf5-static.dir/H5Ztrans.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x3686): undefined reference to `__isa_available'
D:/My_Working_Apps/Anaconda3/Library/lib/libhdf5.lib(CMakeFiles/hdf5-static.dir/H5Ztrans.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x39b5): undefined reference to `__isa_available'
D:/My_Working_Apps/Anaconda3/Library/lib/libhdf5.lib(CMakeFiles/hdf5-static.dir/H5Z.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x36f): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
D:/My_Working_Apps/Anaconda3/Library/lib/libhdf5.lib(CMakeFiles/hdf5-static.dir/H5Z.c.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$H5Z_prepare_prelude_callback_dcpl]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
D:/My_Working_Apps/Anaconda3/Library/lib/libhdf5.lib(CMakeFiles/hdf5-static.dir/H5VM.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x89): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
D:/My_Working_Apps/Anaconda3/Library/lib/libhdf5.lib(CMakeFiles/hdf5-static.dir/H5VM.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xd4): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
...
D:/My_Working_Apps/Anaconda3/Library/lib/libhdf5.lib(CMakeFiles/hdf5-static.dir/H5FAtest.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x7f): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
D:/My_Working_Apps/Anaconda3/Library/lib/libhdf5.lib(CMakeFiles/hdf5-static.dir/H5FAtest.c.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$H5FA__test_debug]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
D:/My_Working_Apps/Anaconda3/Library/lib/libhdf5.lib(CMakeFiles/hdf5-static.dir/H5EAtest.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x7f): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
D:/My_Working_Apps/Anaconda3/Library/lib/libhdf5.lib(CMakeFiles/hdf5-static.dir/H5EAtest.c.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$H5EA__test_debug]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules\world\CMakeFiles\opencv_world.dir\build.make:18531: bin/libopencv_world470.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:2529: modules/world/CMakeFiles/opencv_world.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:165: all] Error 2
```

```
cmake configuration：
General configuration for OpenCV 4.7.0-dev =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            D:/My_Data/2_Cpp_Libs/opencv_contrib-4.7.0/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2023-06-06T01:47:09Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.22621 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.23.4
    CMake generator:             MinGW Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            D:/My_Data/x86_64-8.1.0-release-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (16 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (32 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                D:/My_Data/x86_64-8.1.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/g++.exe  (ver 8.1.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  D:/My_Data/x86_64-8.1.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--gc-sections  
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--gc-sections  
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          pthread
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco barcode bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann fuzzy gapi hdf hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform line_descriptor mcc ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot quality rapid reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab wechat_qrcode world xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    java_bindings_generator js_bindings_generator python3 python_bindings_generator python_tests
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 alphamat cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv freetype java julia matlab ovis python2 python2 sfm viz
    Applications:                apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         YES

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI: 
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.13)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.3-62)
      SIMD Support Request:      YES
      SIMD Support:              NO
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES

  Parallel framework:            pthreads

  Trace:                         YES (built-in)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
    Include path:                D:/My_Data/2_Cpp_Libs/opencv-4.7.0/sources/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python (for build):            D:/My_Working_Apps/Anaconda3/python.exe

  Install to:                    D:/My_Data/2_Cpp_Libs/opencv-4.7.0-build/install
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried changing opencv version, 4.5.5/4.6.0/4.7.0, the error is same.
And if just compile opencv(without opencv-contrib), the error disappear.
The error info show anaconda3, I do not know why the conda effect c++  compile